# Getting number of processed items in ChunkListener in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring-batch

I've been trying to save to the database the number of items processed by my Batch Jobs.

My initial idea was to use the afterWrite method of an ItemWriteListener since it receives the list of items as a parameter, I would take the size of the list and increment the value in my database.

```
afterWrite(List<? extends S> items){
saveToDatabase(items.size)
}
```

This worked but later I found out the afterWrite executes before the commit and I wanted to save this info after the commit was done.

So I took a look at the documentation and found out that the afterChunk method of the ChunkListener executes after the commit is made. However it receives the ChunkContext parameter instead which doesn't seem to have the information about number of items (the commit count and read count don't seem to match the exact number I need)

So I need a way to access the processed item list size in the ChunkListener (assuming it is possible), do you have any advice you can give me?

Answer (score 0):

> I've been trying to save to the database the number of items processed by my Batch Jobs.

This should be equal to (readCount - filterCount). Those counts (as well as the writeCount and skipCount, etc) are already persisted in the BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION table. If you want to save this information to another table, you can do it in a `StepExecutionListener#afterStep`, which gives you a reference to the `StepExecution` from which all these counters are available.

Comment: The counts in the BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION table don't help me, I don't know how spring batch generates those values but they are always different from the actual number of items that are processed. In my case I'm using a jsonItemReader to turn records into items, in an execution where there were 10 items there was a read count of 187 and a commit count of 22.

Comment: An item is the object returned by the Item reader. If the reader returns 10 items and the read count is not equal to 10, then this is either a bug, or the read count in modified inadvertently somewhere in your code.